# Request hitting to Google App Engine Getting Below Information Sometimes and process not executed properly

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt

While my request hits to Google App Engine then sometimes getting Below Getting Message. Due to this some process is processed and rest is exist.
Due to this My application not working in Production

Why I am getting this message for:

```
2019-10-31 20:47:19.972 IST
A problem was encountered with the process that handled this request,
causing it to exit. This is likely to cause a new process to be used for the 
next request to your application. If you see this message frequently, you may be 
throwing exceptions during the initialization of your application. 
(Error code 104)
```

And This happens not only one request it happens any request.

Any help
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java, if a “DeadlineExceededException” happens and it’s not caught, an uncatchable HardDeadlineExceededError is thrown and If concurrent requests are enabled through the "threadsafe" flag, every other running concurrent request is killed and you may receive such message. You can find more information about this here [DeadlineExceededException](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/javadoc/com/google/apphosting/api/DeadlineExceededException)